# automatically open TagBar

Tags: tabbed-user-interface, plugin-tagbar

I set *Tagbar* automatically open when a new file in vim, it is ok and fine.
but if open a new file as a tab in opened vim, *Tagbar* would not be opened, how to tell vim to keep open *Tagbar* open with a new tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me such line in `.vimrc` does the job:

```
autocmd FileType python,c,cpp TagbarOpen
```

Comment: how to set it for all type file?

Comment: Try add this line: 
"autocmd BufNew,BufRead,BufEnter * TagbarOpen". But do you really need Tagbar on text files for example?